# Error: Can not run this platform with administrative permissions Cordova

Tags: cordova, windows-phone

I'm trying to run my app on my windows phone, however
when I do `cordova run windows` it builds the file, then says that 
`Your package has been successfully created.`

But the next line says this:

```
Error: Can not run this platform with administrative permissions. Must be run from a non-admin prompt.
```

If I boot up the cmd without Admin rights, then I get into the network location, instead of c:/
so I can't run my cordova script to run the app there.

I've also tried to run from Visual studio 2015, but there's my `device` option as target, there are only browsers / emulators.

I tried doing

```
cordova platform add wp8
```

Which added the windows platform, but gave me a warning that wp8 was deprecated, and that I should use windows instead.

but

```
cordova run wp8
```

does work, is this the correct way of running a windows app to a windows phone?

Comment: No `wp8` in not the correct way to do windows app. It is deprecated since Cordova 6.0.0 : https://cordova.apache.org/news/2016/01/28/tools-release.html

Comment: How can I then get it to run on a Windows phone, using cmd with admin rights